# Cannot Install jade

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install jade in my project folder. But it fails with below issue:

```
-bash-3.2$ npm install jade
npm WARN package.json batchui@0.0.0 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jstransformer/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/void-elements
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: clean-css@'^3.1.9'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.3.3","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.5.0","0.6.0","0.7.0","0.8.0","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.8.3","0.9.0","0.9.1","0.10.0","0.10.1","0.10.2","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","1.0.10","1.0.11","1.0.12","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","1.1.5","1.1.6","1.1.7","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.0.2","2.0.3","2.0.4","2.0.5","2.0.6","2.0.7","2.0.8","2.1.0","2.1.1","2.1.2","2.1.3","2.1.4","2.1.5","2.1.6","2.1.7","2.1.8","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3","2.2.4","2.2.5","2.2.6","2.2.7","2.2.8","2.2.9","2.2.10","2.2.11","2.2.12","2.2.13","2.2.14","2.2.15","2.2.16","2.2.17","2.2.18","2.2.19","2.2.20","2.2.21","2.2.22","3.0.0","3.0.1","3.0.2","2.2.23","3.0.3","3.0.4","3.0.5","3.0.6","3.0.7","3.0.8","3.0.9","3.0.10","3.1.0","3.1.1","3.1.2","3.1.3","3.1.4","3.1.5","3.1.6","3.1.7","3.1.8","3.1.9","3.2.0","3.2.1","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.2.6","3.2.7","3.2.8","3.2.9","3.2.10","3.2.11","3.3.0","3.3.1","3.3.2","3.3.3","3.3.4","3.3.5","3.3.6","3.3.7","3.3.8","3.3.9","3.3.10","3.4.0","3.4.1","3.4.2","3.4.3","3.4.4","3.4.5","3.4.6","3.4.7","3.4.8","3.4.9"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/x/opt/pp/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
npm ERR!     at /x/opt/pp/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/x/opt/pp/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5
npm ERR! command "node" "/x/opt/pp/bin/npm" "install" "jade"
npm ERR! cwd /x/home/ui
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jstransformer/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/void-elements
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /x/home/ui/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please let me know how to resolve the same?

As per request below is the output of npm

-bash-3.2$ npm

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, restart, rm, root,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, version,
    view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /x/home/sprasad/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@1.2.18 /x/opt/pp/lib/node_modules/npm
-bash-3.2$

-bash-3.2$ npm --version
1.2.18
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Hi - looks like a bug in NPM. Could you post the output of `npm --version`?

Comment: You need to add the `--version` flag. `npm --version` EDIT: nvm you're at 1.2.18. Update `npm`.

Comment: But using the latest version still gives me other issues : -bash-3.2$ /x/home/sprasad/nodejs/node-v4.2.6-linux-x64/bin/npm --version
/x/home/sprasad/nodejs/node-v4.2.6-linux-x64/bin/npm: line 2: dirname: command not found
/x/home/sprasad/nodejs/node-v4.2.6-linux-x64/bin/npm: line 2: /node: No such file or directory
/x/home/sprasad/nodejs/node-v4.2.6-linux-x64/bin/npm: line 2: exec: /node: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update NPM; you're at version 1.

```
npm i -g npm@">=3"
```

You might need to run using `sudo`.

After updating, try installing Jade again.

Comment: It seems that in my Unix box command dirname was not there whose functionality is to extract the directory name of the script - changed to hardcoded pathname as in my file system and it works fine. After upgrading to npm version 2.14.12 was successfully able to install jade. Thanks for your pointers